# ConEmu and ASCII characters

Tags: bash, conemu, urxvt, ascii, mintty

I've been using ConEmu for quite a while, and I'm having some problems with ASCII characters in it. This doesn't happen with other terminal emulators, such as urxvt or mintty, here's a shot with the tree of them:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC326.jpg

I'm currently running the bash scripts of pipes.sh and pipesX.sh, which uses the ASCII characters of ┃┏ ┓┛━┓ ┗┃┛┗ ┏━ and ╱╲ respectively. The first ConEmu terminal is running pipesX.sh, and the second ConEmu terminal is running ncmpcpp, where "M-;" was supposed to be »

Comment: Those aren't ASCII characters.  Perhaps they are UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConEmu do not do any magic with your [console application](http://conemu.github.io/en/ConsoleApplication.html) output. Actually, it just shows the contents of the Windows' [real console](http://conemu.github.io/en/RealConsole.html).

However, Windows console supports unicode from WinNT and it's not a problem to use any unicode characters if they exist in the font used to draw console contents: http://conemu.github.io/en/UnicodeSupport.html

However, current cygwin versions and msys v1 are using ANSI for console printouts which leads to limitation of the available character set. AFAIK msys v2 uses unicode and it might act better with UTF-8 glyphs.